# how set value depending on a column value select statement t-sql. Like if 0 set 3, if less than 4 set 2 and so on

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a column named photos, the photos column is of type tinyint and vary from 0 to 8. I want to apply a rank to the column when selecting data from the table. the values that want to get are: if the record has 4 or more photos, it receives a rank of 1. Because it is a fair amount of photos like 5, 6, 7 and 8. if the record has between 1 and 3 set a rank of 2, a medium rank, and if it has no photos set 3. with this and can sort the records based on the number of photos and make my appliation consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you would just use a CASE statement in your ORDER BY.  Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
ORDER BY
   CASE 
   WHEN photos >= 4 THEN 1
   WHEN photos >= 1 THEN 2
   ELSE 3 
   END
```

Or if you wanted it to be an actual column on the table, you could add it as a computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD rank AS 
CASE 
   WHEN photos >= 4 THEN 1
   WHEN photos >= 1 THEN 2
   ELSE 3 
END
```

Comment: When I saw the when keyword and didn't need to read the rest of the code. I had forgotten this syntax. It is the syntax I wanted.